# is there any code to excute "print to figure" in matlab Eye Diagram?

Tags: matlab

I use a matlab function comm.EyeDiagram to draw the eye diagram. Since it is not Figure, I cannot use print to save the picture. I have to print to figure first, then use print function to save it, which means I cannot batch process the picture. Is there any code?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e34oY.png)

```
H = comm.EyeDiagram('SamplesPerSymbol',1,...
'DisplayMode','2D color histogram',...
'YLimits',[min(rx),max(rx)],...
'Position',[640 310 640 560],...
'OversamplingMethod' ,'Input interpolation','ShowGrid',0,...
'ColorFading',1)
```

H(rx)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxHtQ.png)

Comment: There’s also a “print...” option. Does the `print` function not work on that window?

Comment: please avoid a screenshot of code and copy/paste the code into the question using the "code" formatting.

Comment: thank you for your reminder, I edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

This code is taken from the Matlab help for eyediagram:

```
data = randi([0 3],1000,1);
modSig = pskmod(data,4,pi/4);
sps=4;
txfilter = comm.RaisedCosineTransmitFilter('OutputSamplesPerSymbol',sps);
txSig = txfilter(modSig);
h=eyediagram(txSig,2*sps);
print('image.pdf','-dpdf');
```

In this case, the "print" function which OP says failed on comm.EyeDiagram seems to work fine.

Comment: If something is not reproducible, please ask for more details in the comments and vote to close as not-reproducible instead of adding an answer that says so.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi the important part here, if I understood the question correctly, is to use eyediagram, rather than comm.EyeDiagram (which is deprecated but still works). If this does indeed solve the issue then I think it is useful for users to know they should transition to the newer version.